# AS3 code to view flash file in 100%

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

if I open a basic .swf file, and right-click, there's an option to "Show All" or to make it 100%?? How can I code with AS3 so that I don't have to go and click on the 100% option every time???

I'm struggling with this for a while now... If anyone can help me I'll appreciate it a lot!

Thanks! :):)*

Answer (score 0):

In your init code.

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

Comment: Uskali: Thanks for the reply. I found the answer: stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;